# Where to store XML or PHP file when linking Zoho CRM to Kashflow

Tags: php, mysql, xml, api, zoho

I am trying to link Zoho CRM with Kashflow via their API. Zoho CRM stores my contacts and their addresses while through kashflow (online accounting software) I can send invoices. The end result is that I want all my Zoho contact details synced with kashflow. The kashflow website has links to helpful PHP code that I can use to access the kashflow API. [Here is a link to it](http://www.kashflow.com/developers/developer-resources/)! and in zoho there are PHP code snippets that would help me access the contact details.

If I write a .php or xml file that links the two APIs methods where do I store it? I've researched and all I can find are links to MySQL databses or linking the individual APIs to a website. Do I need a website to link the two website programs APIs?

I hope that's not confusing, any tips to point me in the right direction or if anyone knows of a book or guide on how to find your way around APIs in general that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Kashflow offers REST API, try CRM's webhook.

Comment: Great idea, I had a look into it and it looks like a much simpler solution, however you need an enterprise account in Zoho to use webhooks which I don't have available to me (at the moment). Any ideas on using the API?

Comment: In that case, you may want to try some third party services like zapier or ifttt to do this for you.Not sure of the price though. I hope it's cheaper than the Zoho CRM's enterprise pricing.